# Is there a Django 1.7+ replacement for South's add_introspection_rules()?

Tags: django, django-south

Back in the days of South migrations, if you wanted to create a custom model field that extended a Django field's functionality, you could tell South to use the introspection rules of the parent class like so:

```
from south.modelsinspector import add_introspection_rules
add_introspection_rules([], ["^myapp\.stuff\.fields\.SomeNewField"])
```

Now that migrations have been moved to Django, is there a non-South equivalent of the above? Is an equivalent even needed anymore, or is the new migration stuff smart enough to just figure it out on its own?

Comment: Ever find an answer to this?

Comment: When I upgraded to Django 1.7, I removed the call to `add_introspection_rules()` and things seem to "just work", at least for the custom fields that we are using.  There may still be cases where an equivalent of `add_introspection_rules()` is needed, but I haven't found an equivalent, and I haven't come across any specific scenarios, yet, that *need* an equivalent.

Comment: Running into this issue as well. It seems like overriding `deconstruct()` will get you through most issues, but I'm having a problem with Django being unable to serialize non top-level functions.

Comment: `deconstruct` is what corresponds to `add_introspection_rules`; what do you expect from an answer [that is not already covered by the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/custom-model-fields/#custom-field-deconstruct-method)?

Comment: @mattm The introduction of `__qualname__` in python 3 solved most of these issues, though not for lambdas and functions in `<locals>`. On python 2 there is not much we can do afaik, so you'll have to stick with top-level functions.

Comment: @knbk Using the pattern described here https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/22999 got the job done for me.

Comment: @mattm That's a good solution. Just keep in mind this `deconstruct` method is different from the one for `Field` - it should not return a `name`, but just `(path, args, kwargs)`.

Answer (score 8):

As Phillip mentions in the comments, `deconstruct()` *is* the [official way to handle custom fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/custom-model-fields/#custom-field-deconstruct-method) in django migrations.

To go on to complete the request for clarification...  It would appear that there are already a couple of examples of code out there written to handle both.  For example, this excerpt (to handle the `on` parameter for `ExclusiveBooleanField`) is taken from [django-exclusivebooleanfield](https://github.com/anentropic/django-exclusivebooleanfield):

```
from django.db import models, transaction
from django.db.models import Q

from six import string_types
from six.moves import reduce


try:
    transaction_context = transaction.atomic
except AttributeError:
    transaction_context = transaction.commit_on_success


class ExclusiveBooleanField(models.BooleanField):
    """
    Usage:

    class MyModel(models.Model):
        the_one = ExclusiveBooleanField()


    class MyModel(models.Model):
        field_1 = ForeignKey()
        field_2 = CharField()
        the_one = ExclusiveBooleanField(on=('field_1', 'field_2'))
        # `on` is a bit like a unique constraint, value of field
        # is only exclusive for rows with same value of the on fields
    """
    def __init__(self, on=None, *args, **kwargs):
        if isinstance(on, string_types):
            on = (on, )
        self._on_fields = on or ()
        super(ExclusiveBooleanField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def contribute_to_class(self, cls, name):
        super(ExclusiveBooleanField, self).contribute_to_class(cls, name)
        models.signals.class_prepared.connect(self._replace_save, sender=cls)

    def deconstruct(self):
        """
        to support Django 1.7 migrations, see also the add_introspection_rules
        section at bottom of this file for South + earlier Django versions
        """
        name, path, args, kwargs = super(
            ExclusiveBooleanField, self).deconstruct()
        if self._on_fields:
            kwargs['on'] = self._on_fields
        return name, path, args, kwargs

    def _replace_save(self, sender, **kwargs):
        old_save = sender.save
        field_name = self.name
        on_fields = self._on_fields

        def new_save(self, *args, **kwargs):
            def reducer(left, right):
                return left & Q(**{right: getattr(self, right)})

            with transaction_context():
                if getattr(self, field_name) is True:
                    f_args = reduce(reducer, on_fields, Q())
                    u_args = {field_name: False}
                    sender._default_manager.filter(f_args).update(**u_args)
                old_save(self, *args, **kwargs)
        new_save.alters_data = True

        sender.save = new_save


try:
    from south.modelsinspector import add_introspection_rules
    add_introspection_rules(
        rules=[
            (
                (ExclusiveBooleanField,),
                [],
                {"on": ["_on_fields", {"default": tuple()}]},
            )
        ],
        patterns=[
            'exclusivebooleanfield\.fields\.ExclusiveBooleanField',
        ]
    )
except ImportError:
    pass
```

Comment: @mlissner: I think this covers the formal external references and example that you asked for.

Comment: Custom **deconstruct()** method **without using super** -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31953802/upgrading-from-django-1-6-to-1-7-getting-callable-is-not-serialize-when-running