# Django 1.7 migration cannot serialize a class method

Tags: python, django

I have a very basic class that looks something like the following:

```
class Car(Model):

    name = CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)

    @classmethod
    def create_simple_examples(cls):
        for c in ['Sedan', 'Coupe', 'Van', 'SUV']:
            cls.objects.get_or_create(name=c)

    @classmethod
    def get_default(cls):
        c, _ = cls.objects.get_or_create(name='Sedan')
        return c

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

I am trying to add it to a django app.  I have the two class methods to 1. a function to populate the table quickly, and 2. to grab a default one which will be used often.

When I run

```
python manage.py makemigrations myapp
```

I get the following error

```
ValueError: Cannot serialize: <bound method ModelBase.get_default of <class 'crunch.django.myapp.models.Car'>>
```

I am not quite sure why it's trying to serialize my `get_default` function as that's not really part of the migration of the table itself.  Any help would be greatly appreciated

**UPDATE** I think I may have found the source of the problem (still not sure how to fix it though...)

I have other classes that are FKing to my new class, and the default uses my default above...something like this

```
class OtherClass(Model):

    car = ForeignKey(Car, default=Car.get_default)
```

It looks like the migration is trying to serialize the function because of this.  Any tips on how to get around this?

Comment: try to move default to save method or post_save etc

Comment: How did you get this to work, finally?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the `@deconstructible` decorator to the classes which have a `classmethod`

```
from django.utils.deconstruct import deconstructible

@deconstructible
class Car(Model):
    ...
```

More documentation on [`deconstructible`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/migrations/#adding-a-deconstruct-method) can be found here

Comment: I had the same problem and added this decorator to the class with the `classmethod`s, but Django is still giving the same error when I migrate... what could the reason?

Comment: did you clear the stale pyc files and try again ? I could also imagine a situation where the error is at the next occurance. It would be hard to speculate without seeing the stacktrace, etc..

Comment: Custom **deconstruct()** method, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31953802/upgrading-from-django-1-6-to-1-7-getting-callable-is-not-serialize-when-running

Answer (score 3):

As explained in [Django's migrations docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/migrations/#migration-serializing), Django can serialize function and method references, (in Python 3) unbound methods used from within the class body, and a bunch of other stuff, but it can't serialize everything.

In this case, because you've made `get_default` a `@classmethod`, `Car.get_default` is a bound method (i.e., it takes an implicit reference to `Car` as its first parameter), rather than a plain function or method reference, and Django doesn't know what to do with that.

Try making `get_default` a `@staticmethod` instead, or make a free function (top-level function) that calls `Car.get_default`.

Comment: making it a fee standing function fixed it for me.