# Django model class can't be serialized due to `default=` field parameter poiting to class method

Tags: python, django, django-models

In a Django project I've the following models:

```py
class Asset(Model):
    code = SlugField(max_length=DEFAULT_CODE_LENGTH)
    name = CharField(max_length=DEFAULT_NAME_LENGTH)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    def __eq__(self, other: object) -> bool:
        return isinstance(other, type(self)) and self.code == other.code

    def __hash__(self) -> int:
        return hash(self.code)


class District(Asset):
    # ... class-specific fields
```

I would like to add some logic in order that when instancing an `Asset` subclass the `code` field is automatically filled. I thought that an elegant way to do it could be modifying the `Asset` class:

```py
class Asset(Model):
    @classmethod
    def generate_code(cls) -> str:
        return unique_code_generation_logic(model=cls, length=DEFAULT_CODE_LENGTH)

    code = SlugField(max_length=DEFAULT_CODE_LENGTH, unique=True, default=generate_code)
    name = CharField(max_length=DEFAULT_NAME_LENGTH)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

def unique_code_generation_logic(model: type, length: int) -> str:
    # generating a new code and verifying that is unique for the model class
    return code
```

But Django does not allow to declare it because the class method can't be serialized:

```
user@PC in repo: backend on  feature/task-989_models [$x!?2⇣12] via  v3.10.2 (.venv) took 3ms
λ ./manage.py makemigrations kmap core
Migrations for 'core':
  core/migrations/0001_initial.py
    - Create model District
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/django_project/backend/./manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/user/django_project/backend/./manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/user/django_project/backend/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 425, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/user/django_project/backend/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 419, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/user/django_project/backend/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 373, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/user/django_project/backend/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 417, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/user/django_project/backend/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 90, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user/django_project/backend/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/makemigrations.py", line 190, in handle
    self.write_migration_files(changes)
  File "/home/user/django_project/backend/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/makemigrations.py", line 227, in write_migration_files
    migration_string = writer.as_string()
  File "/home/user/django_project/backend/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/migrations/writer.py", line 141, in as_string
    operation_string, operation_imports = OperationWriter(operation).serialize()
  File "/home/user/django_project/backend/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/migrations/writer.py", line 99, in serialize
    _write(arg_name, arg_value)
  File "/home/user/django_project/backend/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/migrations/writer.py", line 51, in _write
    arg_string, arg_imports = MigrationWriter.serialize(item)
  File "/home/user/django_project/backend/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/migrations/writer.py", line 271, in serialize
    return serializer_factory(value).serialize()
  File "/home/user/django_project/backend/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/migrations/serializer.py", line 39, in serialize
    item_string, item_imports = serializer_factory(item).serialize()
  File "/home/user/django_project/backend/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/migrations/serializer.py", line 201, in serialize
    return self.serialize_deconstructed(path, args, kwargs)
  File "/home/user/django_project/backend/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/migrations/serializer.py", line 88, in serialize_deconstructed
    arg_string, arg_imports = serializer_factory(arg).serialize()
  File "/home/user/django_project/backend/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/migrations/serializer.py", line 353, in serializer_factory
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Cannot serialize: <classmethod(<function Asset.generate_code at 0x7fcadc7d5d80>)>
There are some values Django cannot serialize into migration files.
For more, see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/migrations/#migration-serializing
```

So how could it be done?

Comment: I've already tried that solution, but since it does not make sense to me I decided to write my own question. I think that the [second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32016603/3932902) is the right one, but since it was wrote down 7 years ago I was hoping that something has been done to fulfill the gap.

Comment: I think the first answer, adding a `@deconstructible` decorator to your model is the right approach.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/migrations/#adding-a-deconstruct-method explains how to deal with migrations too.

Comment: Adding the `@deconstructible` annotations does not work for me, it still gives me the same error reported in the question.

I don't know if it helps but if I remove the `default=...` parameter from the `Asset.code` field declaration Django works careless the presence of the `@deconstructible` annotation.

Comment: I edited the question body adding the `__eq__()` method, as suggested in the article reported by Jacques Gaudin.

Comment: Shouldn't the `__eq__` function test if **instances** are equal?

Comment: In fact it states that two instances are equal if their `code` are equal, but before ensures that the two objects are instances of the `Asset` class.

Comment: Sure but then why is the default code obtained from `generate_code`  the same for all instances?

Comment: The code generated by `generate_code` is unique (the function once generates the code checks that is not used by any other `cls` instance), but in case someone will manually assign it a value already existing in the database the new instance will overwrite the older one. But how is the `__eq__()` implementation relevant to the question topic?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242065/discussion-between-jacques-gaudin-and-el-quero).