# What's the purpose of Django "deconstruct" model field function?

Tags: python, django

In order to develop custom Django model fields, I'm reading the documentation.

I have already developed my custom field (which is almost equal to that of the example, `HandField`: a field mapped over a Python class... With the only difference that I inherit from `models.CharField` and not `models.Field`).

```
from external_library import ExternalClass

class ExternalClassField(models.CharField):
    description = "An ExternalClass field"

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['max_length'] = 14
        super(ExternalClassField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def from_db_value(self, value, expression, connection, context):
        if value is None:
            return value
        return ExternalClass(value)

    def to_python(self, value):
        if isinstance(value, ExternalClass):
            return value

        if value is None:
            return value

        return ExternalClass(value)

    def get_prep_value(self, value):
        if value is None:
            return value

        if isinstance(value, ExternalClass):
            return value.to_string()

        return value
```

The field behave as expected. However, I'm stuck at this part of the documentation: the [deconstruct()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/custom-model-fields/#field-deconstruction) function.

In particular, what I don't understand is this:

- What exactly is the purpose of the deconstruct function?
- How come my field works perfectly well even without it (and even if I modify the `init` arguments)?
- How and when is that Django calls the deconstruct function?

I don't want to blindly copy-paste code that I don't understand, but the documentation is not clear.

Comment: It's used in migrations to serialize the field.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The `deconstruct()` method is used to help perform model migrations that aren't able to automatically be handled by the system. Let's walk through a scenario where deconstruct would get called.

Let's say we had some model, and we added a custom field to it. The we try to migrate with `python manage.py makemigrations`.

We encounter the following error:

```
ValueError: Cannot serialize: Foo
There are some values Django cannot serialize into migration files.
```

It turns out that there's already [a related ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/24631) that's been filed with the Django Project, let's check it out.

[image: ticket-issue]

One of the core developers responded that this is intended behavior, because our field contains a callable.

[image: ticket-resolution]

So, we missed something in the documentation. There's a callable value being stored, and it can't be automatically migrated for some reason. What can we do?

Well, in addition to telling us about the `ValueError`, `manage.py` also gave us a useful link to the documentation:

[image: docs-link]

Once on that page, scroll down a bit, until we get to the section about [serializing values](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/migrations/#serializing-values).

> Django can serialize the following:
>
> - ...
> - Anything with a custom deconstruct() method (see below)
> - ...

Well, let's [see below](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/migrations/#adding-a-deconstruct-method):

> You can let Django serialize your own custom class instances by giving
>   the class a deconstruct() method. It takes no arguments, and should
>   return a tuple of three things (path, args, kwargs):
>
> - **path** should be the Python path to the class, with the class name
>     included as the last part (for example, myapp.custom_things.MyClass).
>     If your class is not available at the top level of a module it is not
>     serializable.
> - **args** should be a list of positional arguments to pass to
>     your class’ **init** method. Everything in this list should itself be
>     serializable.
> - **kwargs** should be a dict of keyword arguments to pass to
>     your class’ **init** method. Every value should itself be
>     serializable.

Note that the deconstruct() method works hand in hand with `__eq__()`, as stated by the documentation:

> To prevent a new migration from being created each time makemigrations is run, you should also add a **__eq__()** method to the decorated class. This function will be called by Django’s migration framework to detect changes between states.

In my case, the mistake was adding parenthesis after a value that should not have been called, but in many cases you'll want to implement that deconstruct method for migrations. (Here's another [useful link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29551367/is-there-a-django-1-7-replacement-for-souths-add-introspection-rules) that has an example.)

Comment: I'd wish there's more answers like this on on SO!

Comment: For some reason, I didn't accept the answer. Really sorry for that: answer accepted. Really insightful and useful, thanks!